# Not able to include css file in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to use below code in vf page. but no luck.
could anyone please help me with below code.

Here in below code i am trying to design below widgets[image]

```
<apex:page >
<apex:stylesheet value="Resource/Dashing/templates/project/assets/stylesheets/application.css" />
<apex:form >
<div class="gridster">
  <ul>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
      <div data-id="karma" data-view="Number" data-title="Karma" style="background-color:#96bf48;"></div>
    </li>

    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
      <div data-id="valuation" data-view="Number" data-title="Current Valuation" data-prefix="$"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Application.css

```
@font-face {   font-family: "FontAwesome";   src: url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot');   src: url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');   font-weight: normal;   font-style: normal; }

/*  Font Awesome styles
    ------------------------------------------------------- */ [class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {   font-family: FontAwesome;   font-weight: normal;   font-style: normal;   display: inline-block;   text-decoration: inherit; } a [class^="icon-"], a [class*=" icon-"] {   display: inline-block;   text-decoration: inherit; } /* makes the font 33% larger relative to the icon container
*/ .icon-large:before {   vertical-align: top;   font-size: 1.3333333333333333em; } .btn [class^="icon-"], .btn [class*=" icon-"] {   /* keeps button heights with and without icons the same */

  line-height: .9em; } li [class^="icon-"], li [class*=" icon-"] {   display: inline-block;   width: 1.25em;   text-align: center; } li .icon-large[class^="icon-"], li .icon-large[class*=" icon-"] {   /*
1.5 increased font size for icon-large * 1.25 width */

  width: 1.875em; } li[class^="icon-"], li[class*=" icon-"] {   margin-left: 0;   list-style-type: none; } li[class^="icon-"]:before, li[class*=" icon-"]:before {   text-indent: -2em;   text-align: center; } li[class^="icon-"].icon-large:before, li[class*=" icon-"].icon-large:before {   text-indent: -1.3333333333333333em; } /* Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure screen
    readers do not read off random characters that represent icons */ .icon-glass:before                { content: "\f000"; } .icon-music:before                { content: "\f001"; } .icon-search:before               { content: "\f002"; } .icon-envelope:before             { content: "\f003"; } .icon-heart:before                { content: "\f004"; } .icon-star:before                 { content: "\f005"; } .icon-star-empty:before           { content: "\f006"; } .icon-user:before                 { content: "\f007"; } .icon-film:before                 { content: "\f008"; } .icon-th-large:before             { content: "\f009"; } .icon-th:before                   { content: "\f00a"; } .icon-th-list:before              { content: "\f00b"; } .icon-ok:before                   { content: "\f00c"; } .icon-remove:before               { content: "\f00d"; } .icon-zoom-in:before              { content: "\f00e"; }

.icon-zoom-out:before             { content: "\f010"; } .icon-off:before                  { content: "\f011"; } .icon-signal:before               { content: "\f012"; } .icon-cog:before                  { content: "\f013"; } .icon-trash:before                { content: "\f014"; } .icon-home:before                 { content: "\f015"; } .icon-file:before                 { content: "\f016"; } .icon-time:before                 { content: "\f017"; } .icon-road:before                 { content: "\f018"; } .icon-download-alt:before         { content: "\f019"; } .icon-download:before             { content: "\f01a"; } .icon-upload:before               { content: "\f01b"; } .icon-inbox:before                { content: "\f01c"; } .icon-play-circle:before          { content: "\f01d"; } .icon-repeat:before               { content: "\f01e"; }

/* \f020 doesn't work in Safari. all shifted one down */ .icon-refresh:before              { content: "\f021"; } .icon-list-alt:before             { content: "\f022"; } .icon-lock:before                 { content: "\f023"; } .icon-flag:before                 { content: "\f024"; } .icon-headphones:before           { content: "\f025"; } .icon-volume-off:before           { content: "\f026"; } .icon-volume-down:before          { content: "\f027"; } .icon-volume-up:before            { content: "\f028"; } .icon-qrcode:before               { content: "\f029"; } .icon-barcode:before              { content: "\f02a"; } .icon-tag:before                  { content: "\f02b"; } .icon-tags:before                 { content: "\f02c"; } .icon-book:before                 { content: "\f02d"; } .icon-bookmark:before             { content: "\f02e"; } .icon-print:before                { content: "\f02f"; }

.icon-camera:before               { content: "\f030"; } .icon-font:before                 { content: "\f031"; } .icon-bold:before                 { content: "\f032"; } .icon-italic:before               { content: "\f033"; } .icon-text-height:before          { content: "\f034"; } .icon-text-width:before           { content: "\f035"; } .icon-align-left:before           { content: "\f036"; } .icon-align-center:before         { content: "\f037"; } .icon-align-right:before          { content: "\f038"; } .icon-align-justify:before        { content: "\f039"; } .icon-list:before                 { content: "\f03a"; } .icon-indent-left:before          { content: "\f03b"; } .icon-indent-right:before         { content: "\f03c"; } .icon-facetime-video:before       { content: "\f03d"; } .icon-picture:before              { content: "\f03e"; }

.icon-pencil:before               { content: "\f040"; } .icon-map-marker:before           { content: "\f041"; } .icon-adjust:before               { content: "\f042"; } .icon-tint:before                 { content: "\f043"; } .icon-edit:before                 { content: "\f044"; } .icon-share:before                { content: "\f045"; } .icon-check:before                { content: "\f046"; } .icon-move:before                 { content: "\f047"; } .icon-step-backward:before        { content: "\f048"; } .icon-fast-backward:before        { content: "\f049"; } .icon-backward:before             { content: "\f04a"; } .icon-play:before                 { content: "\f04b"; } .icon-pause:before                { content: "\f04c"; } .icon-stop:before                 { content: "\f04d"; } .icon-forward:before              { content: "\f04e"; }

.icon-fast-forward:before         { content: "\f050"; } .icon-step-forward:before         { content: "\f051"; } .icon-eject:before                { content: "\f052"; } .icon-chevron-left:before         { content: "\f053"; } .icon-chevron-right:before        { content: "\f054"; } .icon-plus-sign:before            { content: "\f055"; } .icon-minus-sign:before           { content: "\f056"; } .icon-remove-sign:before          { content: "\f057"; } .icon-ok-sign:before              { content: "\f058"; } .icon-question-sign:before        { content: "\f059"; } .icon-info-sign:before            { content: "\f05a"; } .icon-screenshot:before           { content: "\f05b"; } .icon-remove-circle:before        { content: "\f05c"; } .icon-ok-circle:before            { content: "\f05d"; } .icon-ban-circle:before           { content: "\f05e"; }

.icon-arrow-left:before           { content: "\f060"; } .icon-arrow-right:before          { content: "\f061"; } .icon-arrow-up:before             { content: "\f062"; } .icon-arrow-down:before           { content: "\f063"; } .icon-share-alt:before            { content: "\f064"; } .icon-resize-full:before          { content: "\f065"; } .icon-resize-small:before         { content: "\f066"; } .icon-plus:before                 { content: "\f067"; } .icon-minus:before                { content: "\f068"; } .icon-asterisk:before             { content: "\f069"; } .icon-exclamation-sign:before     { content: "\f06a"; } .icon-gift:before                 { content: "\f06b"; } .icon-leaf:before                 { content: "\f06c"; } .icon-fire:before                 { content: "\f06d"; } .icon-eye-open:before             { content: "\f06e"; }

.icon-eye-close:before            { content: "\f070"; } .icon-warning-sign:before         { content: "\f071"; } .icon-plane:before                { content: "\f072"; } .icon-calendar:before             { content: "\f073"; } .icon-random:before               { content: "\f074"; } .icon-comment:before              { content: "\f075"; } .icon-magnet:before               { content: "\f076"; } .icon-chevron-up:before           { content: "\f077"; } .icon-chevron-down:before         { content: "\f078"; } .icon-retweet:before              { content: "\f079"; } .icon-shopping-cart:before        { content: "\f07a"; } .icon-folder-close:before         { content: "\f07b"; } .icon-folder-open:before          { content: "\f07c"; } .icon-resize-vertical:before      { content: "\f07d"; } .icon-resize-horizontal:before    { content: "\f07e"; }

.icon-bar-chart:before            { content: "\f080"; } .icon-twitter-sign:before         { content: "\f081"; } .icon-facebook-sign:before        { content: "\f082"; } .icon-camera-retro:before         { content: "\f083"; } .icon-key:before                  { content: "\f084"; } .icon-cogs:before                 { content: "\f085"; } .icon-comments:before             { content: "\f086"; } .icon-thumbs-up:before            { content: "\f087"; } .icon-thumbs-down:before          { content: "\f088"; } .icon-star-half:before            { content: "\f089"; } .icon-heart-empty:before          { content: "\f08a"; } .icon-signout:before              { content: "\f08b"; } .icon-linkedin-sign:before        { content: "\f08c"; } .icon-pushpin:before              { content: "\f08d"; } .icon-external-link:before        { content: "\f08e"; }

.icon-signin:before               { content: "\f090"; } .icon-trophy:before               { content: "\f091"; } .icon-github-sign:before          { content: "\f092"; } .icon-upload-alt:before           { content: "\f093"; } .icon-lemon:before                { content: "\f094"; } .icon-phone:before                { content: "\f095"; } .icon-check-empty:before          { content: "\f096"; } .icon-bookmark-empty:before       { content: "\f097"; } .icon-phone-sign:before           { content: "\f098"; } .icon-twitter:before              { content: "\f099"; } .icon-facebook:before             { content: "\f09a"; } .icon-github:before               { content: "\f09b"; } .icon-unlock:before               { content: "\f09c"; } .icon-credit-card:before          { content: "\f09d"; } .icon-rss:before                  { content: "\f09e"; }

.icon-hdd:before                  { content: "\f0a0"; } .icon-bullhorn:before             { content: "\f0a1"; } .icon-bell:before                 { content: "\f0a2"; } .icon-certificate:before          { content: "\f0a3"; } .icon-hand-right:before           { content: "\f0a4"; } .icon-hand-left:before            { content: "\f0a5"; } .icon-hand-up:before              { content: "\f0a6"; } .icon-hand-down:before            { content: "\f0a7"; } .icon-circle-arrow-left:before    { content: "\f0a8"; } .icon-circle-arrow-right:before   { content: "\f0a9"; } .icon-circle-arrow-up:before      { content: "\f0aa"; } .icon-circle-arrow-down:before    { content: "\f0ab"; } .icon-globe:before                { content: "\f0ac"; } .icon-wrench:before               { content: "\f0ad"; } .icon-tasks:before                { content: "\f0ae"; }

.icon-filter:before               { content: "\f0b0"; } .icon-briefcase:before            { content: "\f0b1"; } .icon-fullscreen:before           { content: "\f0b2"; }

.icon-group:before                { content: "\f0c0"; } .icon-link:before                 { content: "\f0c1"; } .icon-cloud:before                { content: "\f0c2"; } .icon-beaker:before               { content: "\f0c3"; } .icon-cut:before                  { content: "\f0c4"; } .icon-copy:before                 { content: "\f0c5"; } .icon-paper-clip:before           { content: "\f0c6"; } .icon-save:before                 { content: "\f0c7"; } .icon-sign-blank:before           { content: "\f0c8"; } .icon-reorder:before              { content: "\f0c9"; } .icon-list-ul:before              { content: "\f0ca"; } .icon-list-ol:before              { content: "\f0cb"; } .icon-strikethrough:before        { content: "\f0cc"; } .icon-underline:before            { content: "\f0cd"; } .icon-table:before                { content: "\f0ce"; }

.icon-magic:before                { content: "\f0d0"; } .icon-truck:before                { content: "\f0d1"; } .icon-pinterest:before            { content: "\f0d2"; } .icon-pinterest-sign:before       { content: "\f0d3"; } .icon-google-plus-sign:before     { content: "\f0d4"; } .icon-google-plus:before          { content: "\f0d5"; } .icon-money:before                { content: "\f0d6"; } .icon-caret-down:before           { content: "\f0d7"; } .icon-caret-up:before             { content: "\f0d8"; } .icon-caret-left:before           { content: "\f0d9"; } .icon-caret-right:before          { content: "\f0da"; } .icon-columns:before              { content: "\f0db"; } .icon-sort:before                 { content: "\f0dc"; } .icon-sort-down:before            { content: "\f0dd"; } .icon-sort-up:before              { content: "\f0de"; }

.icon-envelope-alt:before         { content: "\f0e0"; } .icon-linkedin:before             { content: "\f0e1"; } .icon-undo:before                 { content: "\f0e2"; } .icon-legal:before                { content: "\f0e3"; } .icon-dashboard:before            { content: "\f0e4"; } .icon-comment-alt:before          { content: "\f0e5"; } .icon-comments-alt:before         { content: "\f0e6"; } .icon-bolt:before                 { content: "\f0e7"; } .icon-sitemap:before              { content: "\f0e8"; } .icon-umbrella:before             { content: "\f0e9"; } .icon-paste:before                { content: "\f0ea"; }

.icon-user-md:before              { content: "\f200"; } /*! gridster.js - v0.1.0 - 2012-08-14
* http://gridster.net/
* Copyright (c) 2012 ducksboard; Licensed MIT */


.gridster {
    position:relative; }

.gridster > * {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: height .4s;
    -moz-transition: height .4s;
    -o-transition: height .4s;
    -ms-transition: height .4s;
    transition: height .4s; }

.gridster .gs_w{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute; }

.ready .gs_w:not(.preview-holder) {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s; }

.gridster .preview-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.3; }

.gridster .player-revert {
    z-index: 10!important;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s, top .3s!important;
    -moz-transition: left .3s, top .3s!important;
    -o-transition: left .3s, top .3s!important;
    transition:  left .3s, top .3s!important; }

.gridster .dragging {
    z-index: 10!important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0s !important;
    -o-transition: all 0s !important;
    transition: all 0s !important; }

/* Uncomment this if you set helper : "clone" in draggable options */ /*.gridster .player {   opacity:0; }*/ .widget-clock {   background-color: #dc5945; } .widget-comments {   background-color:
#eb9c3c; }   .widget-comments .title {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    margin-bottom: 15px; }   .widget-comments .name {
    padding-left: 5px; }   .widget-comments .comment-container {
    display: none; }   .widget-comments .more-info {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); } .widget-graph {   background-color: #dc5945;   position: relative; }   .widget-graph svg {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.4;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px; }   .widget-graph .title, .widget-graph .value {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99; }   .widget-graph .title {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-graph .more-info {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0; }   .widget-graph .x_tick {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; }
    .widget-graph .x_tick .title {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      opacity: 0.5;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }   .widget-graph .y_ticks {
    font-size: 20px;
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    fill-opacity: 1; }   .widget-graph .domain {
    display: none; } .widget-iframe {   padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px !important; }   .widget-iframe iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; } .widget-image {   background-color: #4b4b4b; } .widget-list {   background-color: #12b0c5;   vertical-align: top; }   .widget-list .title {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-list ol, .widget-list ul {
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-list ol {
    list-style-position: inside; }   .widget-list li {
    margin-bottom: 5px; }   .widget-list .list-nostyle {
    list-style: none; }   .widget-list .label {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-list .value {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white; }   .widget-list .updated-at {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }   .widget-list .more-info {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); } .widget-meter {   background-color: #9c4274; }   .widget-meter input.meter {
    background-color: #662b4c;
    color: #fff; }   .widget-meter .title {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-meter .more-info {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }   .widget-meter .updated-at {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); } .widget-number {   background-color: #47bbb3; }   .widget-number .title {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-number .value {
    color: white; }   .widget-number .change-rate {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white; }   .widget-number .more-info {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-number .updated-at {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); } .widget-text {   background-color: #ec663c; }   .widget-text .title {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-text .more-info {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-text .updated-at {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }   .widget-text.large h3 {
    font-size: 65px; } /*


*/ @-webkit-keyframes status-warning-background {   0% {
    background-color: #e82711; }

  50% {
    background-color: #9b2d23; }

  100% {
    background-color: #e82711; } }

@-webkit-keyframes status-danger-background {   0% {
    background-color: #eeae32; }

  50% {
    background-color: #ff9618; }

  100% {
    background-color: #eeae32; } }

html {   font-size: 100%;   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;  
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body {   margin: 0;   background-color: #222222;   font-size: 20px;   color: white;   font-family: 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

b, strong {   font-weight: bold; }

a {   text-decoration: none;   color: inherit; }

img {   border: 0;   -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;   vertical-align: middle; }

img, object {   max-width: 100%; }

iframe {   max-width: 100%; }

table {   border-collapse: collapse;   border-spacing: 0;   width: 100%; }

td {   vertical-align: middle; }

ul, ol {   padding: 0;   margin: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {   padding: 0;   margin: 0; }

h1 {   margin-bottom: 12px;   text-align: center;   font-size: 30px;   font-weight: 400; }

h2 {   text-transform: uppercase;   font-size: 76px;   font-weight: 700;   color: white; }

h3 {   font-size: 25px;   font-weight: 600;   color: white; }

.gridster {   margin: 0px auto; }

.icon-background {   width: 100% !important;   height: 100%;   position: absolute;   left: 0;   top: 0;   opacity: 0.1;   font-size: 275px; }

.list-nostyle {   list-style: none; }

.gridster ul {   list-style: none; }

.gs_w {   width: 100%;   display: table;   cursor: pointer; }

.widget {   padding: 25px 12px;   text-align: center;   width: 100%;   display: table-cell;   vertical-align: middle; }

.widget.status-warning {   background-color: #e82711;  
-webkit-animation: status-warning-background 2s ease infinite;   -moz-animation: status-warning-background 2s ease infinite;   -ms-animation: status-warning-background 2s ease infinite; }   .widget.status-warning .icon-warning-sign {
    display: inline-block; }   .widget.status-warning .title, .widget.status-warning .more-info {
    color: white; }

.widget.status-danger {   color: white;   background-color: #eeae32;  
-webkit-animation: status-danger-background 2s ease infinite;   -moz-animation: status-danger-background 2s ease infinite;   -ms-animation: status-danger-background 2s ease infinite; }   .widget.status-danger .icon-warning-sign {
    display: inline-block; }   .widget.status-danger .title, .widget.status-danger .more-info {
    color: white; }

.more-info {   font-size: 15px;   position: absolute;   bottom: 32px;  left: 0;   right: 0; }

.updated-at {   font-size: 15px;   position: absolute;   bottom: 12px; left: 0;   right: 0; }

#save-gridster {   display: none;   position: fixed;   top: 0;   margin: 0px auto;   left: 50%;   z-index: 1000;   background: black;   width: 190px;   text-align: center;   border: 1px solid white;   border-top: 0px;   margin-left: -95px;   padding: 15px; }

#save-gridster:hover {   padding-top: 25px; }

#saving-instructions {   display: none;   padding: 10px;   width: 500px;   height: 122px;   z-index: 1000;   background: white;   top: 100px;   color: black;   font-size: 15px;   padding-bottom: 4px; }  
#saving-instructions textarea {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 494px;
    height: 80px; }

#lean_overlay {   position: fixed;   z-index: 100;   top: 0px;   left: 0px;   height: 100%;   width: 100%;   background: #000;   display: none; }

#container {   padding-top: 5px; }

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {   content: "\0020";   display: block;   height: 0;   overflow: hidden; }

.clearfix:after {   clear: both; }

.clearfix {   zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Visualforce resides in the "/apex/" path on the server, but the resources live in the "/resource/" path. This is a problem, because you you used the following path:

```
Resource/Dashing/templates/project/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

This is known as a "relative" path, meaning the browser interprets it as:

```
https://<server>.visual.force.com/apex/Resource/Dashing/templates/project/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

I recommend that you use the $Resource global variable with URLFOR instead:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Dashing, 'templates/project/assets/stylesheets/application.css')}" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't the relative path be `/apex/...`, since that's the root (`/`) directory in this case?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I got lazy and didn't type it out. I just made it the full canonical address instead, which is what I should have done initially.